# C# fuzzy logic tutorial

Tags: c#, fuzzy-logic

hye, can somebody give suggestion where is the best forum or website that i can learn fuzzy logic tutorial in C#. i want to learn about road detection, edge detection and image processing

Comment: I think posting this at dsp.stackexchange.com would have been better.

Comment: Have you searched the internet? Popular search engines find pages with names like "Introduction to C# and Fuzzy Logic".

Comment: @someguy: It could probably go on either site. After all, the line is kind of fuzz.. er, blurry.

Comment: @reuben i tried many keyword but not all link related to what i need

Comment: @kaki That's fair; in the future, though, it would be helpful if you could mention what you did look at and why it was not helpful for what you need. That would help us make sure we're not just doing the same search that you did to answer your question. It will also ensure best results in the answers you get...

Answer (score 11):

The idea behind fuzzy logic is very simple.  I'll attempt an explanation.

So in normal logic you use comparisons such as "i == 1" or " q > 3 and q < 4".

Fuzzy logic, in general is based around the idea that you can have partial matches or partial truths.

So, if I'm searching for someone with the last name "Hamilton"  and I type in "Hamelton" instead, normal logic would say it was not a match.
Fuzzy logic could return a result like this:

Hamilton has 8 letters, 7 out of the 8 letters match, so that is a .875 match if you divide 7 by 8.

According to some business rules I just made up, anything that has a .75 or greater would constitute a match.

Also, you could blend matching "rules" together and come up with a single scalar to determine a fuzzy match as well.

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 2):

Try [AForge.Net](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/) -- they appear to have what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the respond mate but i already try it. That site help me at certain degree.